# Rails full text search PgSql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, full-text-search

I am working in rails 3.2 and using pgsql, Thing is I want to implement full-text search functionality and after so much googling I did not found anything relevant. Right now I am using search with wild card and its working fine, but I want to implement full text search

```
Event.select('event_name,id').find(:all, :conditions => ['lower(event_name) LIKE ?', "%#{params[:keyword].downcase}%"])
```

Any help would be really appreciate able.

Comment: Have you read the PostgreSQL manual on fulltext search? What's "relevant" if the manual isn't, or the gem linked in the first answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this repo and the post:

1. https://github.com/casecommons/pg_search
2. [pg_search: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love PostgreSQL full-text search](http://pivotallabs.com/pg-search-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-postgresql-full-text-search/)

Comment: I want a simple query of the above query with full-text search I don't want to use any gem for this.

Comment: @ShivAggarwal Why? There are existing tools. If you don't know enough to reinvent them, why not use them? Or otherwise, try reading the PostgreSQL user manual on fulltext search, which is a good starting point if you want to use it with raw SQL.